# Issue sending/receiving data over serial connection using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, serial-port, serial-communication

I recently connected a reactor control tower through a serial 'COMMS' port to my computer (serial to USB). It seems to create a connection on the COM4 port (as indicated on the control panel 'devices and printers' section). However, it always gives me the following message when i try to <s>'fwrite(s)'</s> or 'fscanf(s)'.

> Warning: Unsuccessful read: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period..

```
%My COM4
s = serial('COM4');
s.BaudRate = 9600;
s.DataBits = 8;
s.Parity ='none'; 
s.StopBits = 1;
s.FlowControl='none';
s.Terminator = ';';
s.ByteOrder = 'LittleEndian';
s.ReadAsyncMode = 'manual';

% Building write message.
devID = '02'; % device ID
cmd = 'S'; % command read or write; S for write
readM = cell(961,3);% Read at most 961-by-3 values filling a 961–by–3 matrix in column order

strF = num2str(i); 
strF = '11'; %pH parameter
strP = '15'; %pH set point
val = '006.8'; %pH set value 
msg_  = strcat('!', devID, cmd, strF, strP, val);%output the string
chksum = dec2hex(mod(sum(msg_),256)); %conversion to hexdec
msg = strcat(msg_,':', char(chksum), ';');

fopen(s); %connects s to the device using fopen , writes and reads text data
fwrite(s, uint8(msg)); %writes the binary data/ Convert to 8-bit unsigned integer (unit8) to the instrument connected to s.
reply=fscanf(s); %reads ASCII data from the device connected to the serial port object and returns it to reply, for binary data use fread
fclose(s); %Disconnect s from the scope, and remove s from memory and the workspace.
```

This leads me to believe that the device is connected but is not sending or receiving information and I am unsure as to how I can configure this or even really check if there is communication occurring between the tower and my computer.

Comment: Have you tested communication to the device using a terminal program? Do you actually get the error on trying to execute the `fwrite` command, or only at `fscanf`? Is there any reason you're setting `ReadAsyncMode = 'manual'`, as [the docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serialport-properties.html#mw_2f3c72b3-0e8a-4c90-9f44-48fd1abe2821) definitely suggest to me that `'continuous'` would be more appropriate?

Comment: I have not. I am fairly new to serial I/O to be quite honest. I only get this error whilst trying to either read or write to the reactor tower. What do you think is the advantage of manual over continuous? The reason I believe I am setting 'manual' is because the configuration changes based on a particular time point. The reactor tower has it's own control system embedded into it and the idea is to merely change the setpoints at specific time points vs. controlling it using the desktop.

Comment: **update** I have confirmed that there is no error _(at least on the MATLAB end)_ `fwrite(s, msg)` or `fprintf(s, msg)`. I'm not sure if the machine is receiving and understanding the message hence it is not sending any reply back.

Comment: OK, so you need to troubleshoot this from the ground up. First are you sure the electrical connection is correct - are you using the manufacturer's own cable and/or do you have documentation describing the pinout? Serial connections to instruments are notoriously non-standard. Second, are you sure you're constructing the message and calculating the checksum correctly - if you have docs, is there an example command string you can test it with? A serial tester with LEDs to show the state of each line is really handy here as you can see whether anything is being sent or received.

Comment: I haven't used serial with MATLAB but have done lots of it in other languages and unless I've seriously misunderstood then I'm sure that `continuous` is your correct choice for `ReadAsyncMode`; this has nothing to do with when or how often you're changing the setpoint, it's about how MATLAB configures the serial port for receiving data. `continuous` means the port will always be ready to receive data and will buffer incoming data until it's read.

Comment: Looking at your code I would particularly review how you're doing the checksum. `dec2hex` converts a number into a **hexadecimal string** i.e. a series of characters representing the number in hexadecimal. If your checksum is the number 43 then `dec2hex` will convert it into the two-character string `'2B'`, for example. Check whether that is what the instrument is expecting, rather than the **single byte** 43 (which would be more common in my experience). If it is supposed to be the two-char string then `dec2hex(12)` for example just returns `'C'`, so do you need to add a leading zero?

Comment: The method by which the computer communicates with the serial device was given to me by the supplier. It turns out the issue was on the physical level, I simply had to move around some wires and that was it, the machine talked back, sending replies which I could very easily interpret. Thanks for the help though, it really helped me narrow down the issues by going through them bit by bit.